# adding word to Trie data structure

Tags: haskell

let the Trie data structure and the function to add a string are defined as follows:

```
data Trie = Trie { commonness :: Maybe Int
                 , children :: [(Char, Trie)]
                 } deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

-- trie returns an "empty" Trie
trie :: Trie
trie = Trie { commonness = Nothing, children = [] }


-- Add inserts a word to a Trie with a given frequency
-- stored after the last character
add :: String -> Int -> Trie -> Trie
add [] freq tree = tree { commonness = Just freq }
add (x:xs) freq tree = case lookup x (children tree) of
                        Nothing -> tree { children = (x, add xs freq trie):(children tree) }
                        Just subtree -> tree { children = (x, add xs freq subtree):(mydrop x (children tree)) }
                        where
                            mydrop :: Char -> [(Char, Trie)] -> [(Char, Trie)]
                            mydrop _ [] = []
                            mydrop elm (x:xs)
                                | (fst x) == elm = mydrop elm xs
                                | otherwise = x:(mydrop elm xs)
```

The question is about a better algorithm in case the character already does exist in the current level. I'd like to avoid call of mydrop function and reconstruction of the list of children.

Comment: Could you pick an answer please.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you may optimize `mydrop` function itself in order to stop traversing the list when found the value.

But, IMHO, the only way to optimize the whole `add` function is to merge `lookup` and replacing steps into the one traversal.

```
add' :: String -> Int -> Trie -> Trie
add' [] freq tree = tree { commonness = Just freq }
add' (x:xs) freq tree =
    traverse x (children tree) []
    where
        traverse x [] ts' = tree { children = (x, add' xs freq trie) : ts' }
        traverse x (t:ts) ts' | fst t == x = tree { children = (x, add' xs freq $ snd t) : (ts ++ ts') }
                              | otherwise = traverse x ts (t:ts')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a Map instead of an association list, you can use `alter` with `fromMaybe` to provide an empty `Trie` when the lookup fails:

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Map ( Map )
import Data.Maybe ( fromMaybe )

data Trie = Trie { commonness :: Maybe Int
                 , children :: Map Char Trie
                 } deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

-- trie returns an "empty" Trie
trie :: Trie
trie = Trie { commonness = Nothing, children = Map.empty }

-- Add inserts a word to a Trie with a given frequency
-- stored after the last character
add :: String -> Int -> Trie -> Trie
add [] freq tree = tree { commonness = Just freq }
add (x:xs) freq tree =
  tree { children = Map.alter (Just . add xs freq . fromMaybe trie) x $ children tree }
```